# Is it possible to combine array variable with array number to complete 1 variable?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

My code is as below :
assume that $a is a variable that 1 take out from DB and now i wan to combine it with an array number and produce an output that same with $box. Is it possible to do that ? or i m wrong ? please guide me.. thanks

```
$b="1-1-0-1";
$box=explode("-",$b);
$a="$box"; //from DB
echo $box[2];
echo "$a[1]";
```

Comment: I don't understand your logic, why you need that at all ?

Comment: actually $box is a row title in DB, i cant loop it, so i make another DB table to keep the variable and loop it when the box is being call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$b="1-1-0-1";
$box=explode("-",$b);
$a='$box'; //from DB
$a = substr($a, 1);
echo $box[2];
$c = $$a; 
print_r($c);
```

Comment: how about if the $box is an array ? //for example while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { 
        $box[]=$row['box'];
}// from DB

Comment: $box=explode("-",$b); 
$box is an array too

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes. Why are you so obsessed with them? https://stackoverflow.com/users/2892997/user2892997

```
$a=$box; //from DB
echo $box[2];
echo $a[1];
```

Comment: this '$box' at $a='$box'; is a string not variable I think coming from his DB..

Comment: Nope, look at the line above that. `$box` is the result of explode

Comment: yes, but he comment that its value comes from DB..
How ever, today I see only strange questions here :)

Comment: ya..the $box is a string from DB, i want to make it to become a variable that can combine with the array number.

Comment: 1st $box is array from explode.
2nd $box is string from DB so i want to make it to become variable. is that possible ?

Comment: Nomatter what the box had before, but after executing line 2 of your code, box becomes an array which contains the result of explode. Change the names and update the question

Comment: There are no 1st boxes and second boxes, if you write a new value to a variable with same name then old value is overwritten

Comment: i didn't assign another value to $box, i just assign $box value to another value name $a.

Comment: Read this line of code again: `$box=explode("-",$b);
`